# How to upload file in Google Drive with { google apps script + Reacts js + clasp } web app

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, file-upload, parcel, clasp

Okay I am using react js and parcel along with google apps script to create web application.
Every think working fine and all entries are getting save into google sheet but problem is when it comes to file upload input it only saving local path of file instead of uploading the document into google drive. It is working fine with vanilla JavaScript but don't know why its uploading document what the issue any help much be appreciated.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App () {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    screenShot: ""
  })

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    google.script.run.appendEntry(values);
  
  }

  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                className="form-control form-control-sm"
                name="email"
                type="email"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder="Email"
              />
              <input
                className="form-control form-control-sm"
                name="firstname"
                type="text"
                value={values.firstname}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder="First Name"
              />
              <input
                className="form-control-file"
                type="file"
                name="screenShot"
                value={values.screenShot}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                placeholder="Upload Screenshot"
              />
        </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Code.gs** (backend code)

```
const SheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-zrE_wEoNFaFuGh_9CBvy6shqIBNhaaoML875BLnUxQ/edit#gid=165730349";
const SS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SheetURL);
const WorkSheet = SS.getSheetByName('Portal Responses');

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
    .addMetaTag("viewport", "width=data.device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
}

function appendEntry(data) {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("191THLqPpVIT-1Pdj1ylm1QEskOtV31HD")
    let fileUrl = "";
    if (data.screenShot.length > 0) {
      let blob = data.screenShot;
      let file = folder.createFile(blob)
      file.setDescription(`Uploaded by ${data.firstname}`)
      fileUrl = file.getUrl();
    } else {
      fileUrl = "No File Uploaded";
    }

    let entryWithFile = new Array(
      new Date(),
      data.email,
      data.firstname,
      fileUrl,
      
    )
    WorkSheet.appendRow(entryWithFile)
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` of `HtmlInputElement` type `file` [only contains the string path to the file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file). Furthermore, `file` [isn't a legal parameter to the server](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=en#parameters_and_return_values) (except if it's in a `form` and the form is sent as a whole). Only strings and other primitives are legal parameters. You maybe able to get the data using `HTMLInputElement.files[0]`, use a [`Filereader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to convert the blob data to a `base64` string and send the string to the server and parse it back to binary data server side. But probably the easiest way is to send the form directly:

```
google.script.run.appendEntry(document.querySelector("form"));
```

The server directly parses the names and values to objects and the file input will automatically be cast to `blob` on the server.

Comment: thanks for the comment i got it but when i sending only form data as you mentioned it converting and uploading the file but then i am not able to getting other values such email and firstname probably cause i am using react js framework with parcel so i decided to put state values and form in obj but then its giving error like "Failed due to illegal value in property: file" so i think fileReader is last option to do this

Comment: @KuldeepSingh `but then i am not able to getting other values such email and firstname`. Could you provide the exact error? It's strange that the file is going through, but not the text values.  Provide `console.log(Object.keys(data))` server side. Even if what you're saying is true( highly unlikely), you can always send two values: `google.script.run.appendEntry(values,document.querySelector("form"));` one for text and other for file

Comment: yes that's what I am struggling with since three-day when I used vanilla JavaScript in previous project  I was able to send multiple values in backend even arrays too but don't know why this is not working with React Js and parcel Error showing : - "Uncaught InvalidArgumentError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 1" here is propert 1 is actually form object when i sending it alone its working for file but not values. that's the issue don't know why it's happening not getting another way around

Comment: @KuldeepSingh If it would be better to provide all the logs,  I asked  and all your attempts as a different question with multiple errors, that will be better for all of us.

Comment: sure i am sending the screenshots of  link for Reactform.js and backend.gs and error log here on this drive link you can access it here :- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vNrdst2fHUx8ebBdOkUKX3eD9aeFQ4pp Please check

Comment: @KuldeepSingh I meant as a different new question.. Even in your screenshots, you still didn't provide `Object.keys()` I requested in my previous comment(when sending the form only).

Comment: ohh okay got it I will put another question and will let you know thanks 

Comment: hey finally figured out and Now its worked we can not send string and whole form object together to backend with google run script API so I get file on changes and convert that into 64Base using FileReader() then send it with values string which worked.